# How to create dynamically textboxes in asp.net c# and save info in DB

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I am trying to create dynamically text boxes in asp.net c# with one simple button. But I have no idea how to create them because the code simply does not create the text boxes under the original text boxes.

[Image of the Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTcm5.png)

This is my Asp.NET code:

```
 <div class="card-actions">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnAddBox" OnClick="btnAddBox_Click">
                        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
protected void btnAddBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = "textBox1";
            txt.Text = "helloo";
            Page.Form.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.Add(txt);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

But I am missing the way of saving in the database.

Can somebody help me out with this, or some reference where I can find a sample of code of my need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to get value on button click from dynamic control which was generated on Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731772/i-need-to-get-value-on-button-click-from-dynamic-control-which-was-generated-on)

Comment: There is no correct answer in that post. I need to get value on button click from dynamic control which was generated on Page. It also is omitting the part about capturing the info and save it into the DB. Thanks. Basically the post is uncompleted.