# How to maintain view state of dynamic control linkbutton in C# asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding dynamic LinkButton in Data Gridview, which will take me to a new page in C# asp.net. In starting, I am select value from  Dropdown control. It will reload the page and display data in Gridview. In Gridview every row has dyanmic Linkbutton. When I click on Linkbutton in gridview, it is not working and page was reloaded and it hide the linkbutton.

My code is working when dropdown code pasted on page_load method.

I have researching since last 7 hours, view most of the answers but nothing is working on my problem.

As per my research, I found that after page reload LinkButton lost is state(I am not sure.).

Thanks in Advance...

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace aweFinalTTA.TTA.BatchReport
{
public partial class CenterBatchList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected aweFunctionNew aweApi = new aweFunctionNew();
protected aweCodePublic aweCode = new aweCodePublic();
protected LinkButton linkButton01;
protected GridView gdv;

protected DropDownList ddlTTCCode;



override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

aweApi.showForm(aweApi.getManageFieldDT("select * from manage_field where table_name='TTCBatchList'"), frmBatchList);
ddlTTCCode = (DropDownList)frmBatchList.FindControl(frmBatchList.ID + "ddlTTCCode");
ddlTTCCode.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlTTCCode_SelectedIndexChanged);

frmBatchList.Controls.Add(aweApi.addGridViewNew("EmpGrid", "List of Batch Created"));
gdv = (GridView)frmBatchList.FindControl("EmpGrid");
gdv.RowDataBound += OnRowLinkBound;

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (!IsPostBack)
{

aweApi.getDDL(ddlTTCCode, "select TTCCode,TTCCode from TTCDetail where TTARNO='" + Session["TTARNO_01"].ToString() + "'  and TTCDetail.TTCCode in (Select TTCCode from TTCCourseListOfTTC) and TTCDetail.TTCCode in (Select TTCCode from TTCInfraDetail) and TTCDetail.TTCCode in (Select TTCCode from TTCFacility)  order by LastUpdatedDate   desc", true);
TemplateField tfieldCheckbox = new TemplateField();
tfieldCheckbox.HeaderText = "Select";
gdv.Columns.Add(tfieldCheckbox);

}
}


protected void ddlTTCCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
gdv.DataSource = aweApi.getResultsDT("select * from BatchMain where TTCCode='TTC0000002008'");
gdv.DataBind();
gdv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

}

protected void OnRowLinkBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
linkButton.ID = "link";
linkButton.Text = "Edit";
linkButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
linkButton.Click += linkButton_Click;
e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(linkButton);

}
}

protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//  GridViewRow gr = ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
/// Session["TTCBatchId_01"] = gr.Cells[2].Text.Trim(); /*For first cell value of Row */
Response.Write("linkbutton_click is working");
aweCode.showMessage(this, "aaaaaa");
//Response.Redirect("~/TTA/BatchReport/BatchAddCandidate");
}


}
}
```

Comment: Recreate the controls on PostBack. Viewstate will find them and re-apply the state.

Comment: can you provide any example for your answer. I am beginner and I am not getting your answer. A small example will be very helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731772/i-need-to-get-value-on-button-click-from-dynamic-control-which-was-generated-on

Comment: Thank you, for your Help , My problem solved